# How can I get syntax highlighting for HTML tags in JSON?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, i18next

I have i18next JSON files that contain HTML tags within them, as shown below:

```json
{
"h2": "How to<br /><span className='text-orange-500'>sign</span> up"
}
```

I would like to have proper syntax highlighting for the HTML tags, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Is there any way to achieve this in VS Code?

Comment: how will you determine which strings have HTML text as content

Comment: @rioV8 would it be so bad for all string-typed object values (or just all strings in general) to be treated as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can get html syntax coloring in a `json` file with this setting:

```json
"files.associations": {
  "*.json": "html"
},
```

[image: html syntax colors in a json file]

You can make that more specific like this:

```json
"files.associations": {
  "myComponent.json": "html"
},
```

Comment: Oh Im so sorry for not answering I didnt had notifications on in stack overflow. Sadly this doesnt solve my problem. I would still like to have the json syntax still checked, so I would need a combined mode that is just like the json lang mode but colors the html tags differently